# Teamcity "Failed to find Visual Studio .sln file" error

Tags: github, teamcity

I wrote the right path to github project in teamcity:
[image]

But i am getting the folowing error:
[image]

Teamcity don't fetch the content from the github path.
Do i need to do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add the VCS root to your version control settings in the build configuration, it will extract the source code onto disk.

TeamCity documentation - [Configuring VCS Settings](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+VCS+Settings)

Hope this helps